# How do I optimize this SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

The following is a query that is taking too long; there are a few bits to it but it is otherwise a very simple query. I wanted to ask, can anyone see which part of it might be causing a performance bottleneck? Thanks a million.

```
SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid
  , node_data_field_company_logo.field_company_logo_fid
    AS node_data_field_company_logo_field_company_logo_fid
  , node_data_field_company_logo.field_company_logo_list
    AS node_data_field_company_logo_field_company_logo_list
  , node_data_field_company_logo.field_company_logo_data
    AS node_data_field_company_logo_field_company_logo_data
  , node.type AS node_type, node.vid AS node_vid
  , node_data_field_company_logo.field_job_details_title_value
    AS node_data_field_company_logo_field_job_details_title_value
  , RAND() AS _random
FROM node node
  LEFT JOIN term_node term_node
    ON node.vid = term_node.vid
  LEFT JOIN term_data term_data
    ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid
  LEFT JOIN content_type_profile_job_post node_data_field_company_logo
    ON node.vid = node_data_field_company_logo.vid
WHERE (node.type in ('profile_job_post'))
  AND (node.status <> 0)
  AND ((term_data.name) = (''))
ORDER BY _random ASC
```

Comment: Start off by shortening column aliases?

Comment: Can you please explain table definitions, sample data and the `EXPLAIN` output?

Comment: Perhaps you should *analyze* the query. We have no idea what this does , how the tables are setup, how your indicies are built, etc. MySQL has an EXPLAIN capability.

Comment: Can you define the data and the schema of the tables?

Comment: Why do you alias every column to its existing name?

Comment: @Yann Ramin: as a real *professional* you have to *guess* ;-)

Comment: I reformatted it according to my usual style, as explained in http://bentilly.blogspot.com/2011/02/sql-formatting-style.html.  I did not touch the field names, but they are kind of ridiculous.

Comment: Aliasing tables to their own name (`term_node term_node`) doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's get rid of all those useless aliases. And pay attention to the comments that asked for table structures, indexes, and EXPLAIN output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid
  , node_data_field_company_logo.field_company_logo_fid
  , node_data_field_company_logo.field_company_logo_list
  , node_data_field_company_logo.field_company_logo_data
  , node.type, node.vid
  , node_data_field_company_logo.field_job_details_title_value
  , RAND() AS _random
FROM node 
  LEFT JOIN term_node 
    ON node.vid = term_node.vid
  LEFT JOIN term_data 
    ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid
  LEFT JOIN content_type_profile_job_post 
    ON node.vid = node_data_field_company_logo.vid
WHERE (node.type in ('profile_job_post'))
  AND (node.status <> 0)
  AND ((term_data.name) = (''))
ORDER BY _random ASC
```

Simple things: you'll usually benefit from an index on any column used in a JOIN clause or a WHERE clause.

```
node.status
node.type
node.vid
node_data_field_company_logo.vid
term_data.name
term_data.tid
term_node.vid
```

But it depends on the number of distinct values in each of those columns. For example, if node.status can have only two values, 0 and 1, then an index probably won't help with it. (That's one reason posting your table structures is important.)

Simple things revisited: you're going to pay a heavy price for random order.

Slightly more complex things: you might benefit from creating a view on the node table. The view should select only the columns and rows you actually need here. Then JOIN on that view instead of using the node table directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straightforward.  Here are some obvious things that could improve performance:

1. Why are you sorting by _random?  That will slow you down.
2. Why do you need DISTINCT?  Doing DISTINCT has an implied GROUP BY, which can slow you down.
3. If `(node.type in ('profile_job_post'))` is written as `node.type = 'profile_job_post'` then the optimizer is more likely to notice that it is useful for optimization.

Beyond that, it looks reasonable.  But sanity check.  Do you have all relevant indices?  How big are your tables?  How big is your result set?  How slow is the query?  Can you give us an EXPLAIN plan?

Without that information we just have to guess whether there is a real problem, or whether your expectations are unreasonable.